# Magento 2.1.13 - Add custom link in contact email template

Tags: contact-us

I want to add my custom link in contact email link. For that, I have created a new email template for the contact email but this is in plain text.
[image]

So how can I add a link to contact email template OR how can I overwrite the contact email template in my custom module/theme?

---

As per @VivekKumar answer, please check the below image.

[image]

---

As per @Akhilesh answer, I have overwrite the email_template.xml file in my theme as below. Clear the cache - run content deploy but it loads the template in the plain text.

[image]

Comment: I have used the same code and it works fine for me, try flushing browser and magento cache to see if it fixes the problem

Comment: I have done but it still displays as plain text.

Comment: Is there anyone who knows the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Place your link's html inside **`{{trans '<your html>' |raw}}`** enclosure to ask it to be rendered as html and not as text. So, it should look as follows :

```
{{trans '<a href="www.example.com">example</a>'|raw}}
```

Comment: I tried, please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change the template type to html from text in file

```
vendor/magento/module-contact/etc/email_templates.xml
```

Take this file in your theme folder and change from text to html

```
<template id="contact_email_email_template" label="Contact Form" file="submitted_form.html" type="html" module="Magento_Contact" area="frontend"/>
```

Comment: Seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: Tried but it still loads the template in plain text.

Comment: Changing type of entire email templates to html just to make a link work doesnt seem fine to me.

Comment: @VivekKumar vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php check prepareMessage function. It is checking that template file is plain text or html. getTemplate() function will set the all template variables which we declare in email_templates.xml file.

Comment: @JigarDhaduk Hopefully you deploy and clear cache after making this changes.

Comment: @AkhileshPatel, I have updated the question and also done as per your words still it loads as plain text.